# Rewrites for Magento to get clean urls

Tags: apache, .htaccess, magento, mod-rewrite

I want to rewrite old Magento urls like this, if possible:

1. www.domain.tld/index.php **=>** www.domain.tld/
2. www.domain.tld/index.php/category/ **=>** www.domain.tld/category/
3. www.domain.tld/index.php/category/subcategory/ **=>** www.domain.tld/category/subcategory/

This is how my Magento .htaccess looks like right now (redirecting none of the above).

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on    
RewriteBase /

#RewriteRule ^api/([a-z][0-9a-z_]+)/?$ api.php?type=$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^api/rest api.php?type=rest [QSA,L]
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} ^TRAC[EK]
RewriteRule .* - [L,R=405]
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/mobiledirectoryhere/.*$
#RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "android|blackberry|ipad|iphone|ipod|iemobile|opera mobile|palmos|webos|googlebot-mobile" [NC]
#RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /mobiledirectoryhere/ [L,R=302]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(media|skin|js)/

# REMOVE HOME REWRITE FROM MAGENTO
RewriteRule ^home/?$ /? [R=301,L,NC]

# ADD WWW TO NONE WWW FOR BOTH HTTPS AND NONE HTTPS
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS}s ^on(s)|
RewriteRule ^ http%1://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

#REDIRECT ALL .HTML FILES AND ALL .HTML/ FILES WITH TRAILING SLASH
RewriteRule ^google[0-9a-f]+.html$ - [L]
RewriteRule (.+)\.html$ /$1/ [L,R=301]
RewriteRule (.+)\.html\/$ /$1/ [L,R=301]

# ADD TRAILING SLASH
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

# TRAILING SLASH CHECK
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)/$
#ADD SLASH IF MISSING AND THEN REDIRECT
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1/ [L,R=301]

#CHECK IF REDIRECT POINTS TO A VALID FILE
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

#SEND TO INDEX.PHP FOR CLEAN URLS
#RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L,QSA]
#REWRITE EVERYTHING ELSE TO INDEX.PHP

RewriteRule .* index.php [L]

</IfModule>
```

A big thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0):

In your apache configuration file. e.g. httpd.conf. Append below code with change "Directory" with your actual DocumentRoot for the VirtualHost.

```
<Directory /var/www/html/www>
    AllowOverride All
</Directory>
```

Comment: Thanks, but that is already in the vhost file. The .htaccess file is processed, but does not redirect as I want (see above). I might need some more directives to achieve that? Any other clues, hints, or tips?

Comment: Having Clean URL's configured in Magento your request would work. Use default .htaccess file and verify.

Comment: Thanks for your input KNOWARTH. The internal linking is working as expected. The issue is, I have old links to the site, that is messing up the clean urls I want. For example: a site is linking to www.domaian.tld/index.php, and when and if link is used by a visitor, I want the htaccess to redirect back to root, without the filename index.php and or without query strings (stripped). Possible?